# SQL query _ not able to find recently hired employee is each department

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL SELECT statement to find out the most recently hired employees in EACH department. I am working on Oracle database and am trying to display the department name, employee name, hire date, and salary. The table definition for employee and department tables are below
Department Table

```
CREATE TABLE dpt
( DEPARTMENT_ID         NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  DEPARTMENT_NAME   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS           VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL);
```

Example Data

```
(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
```

Employee Table

```
CREATE TABLE emp 
( EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  JOB           VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  MANAGER_ID    NUMBER(4),HIRE_DATE     DATE,
  SALARY        NUMBER(9, 2),
  COMMISSION    NUMBER(9, 2),
  DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) REFERENCES dpt(DEPARTMENT_ID));
```

Example Data

```
 (7839, 'KING',  'PRESIDENT', NULL, '20-NOV-01', 5000, NULL, 50);
 (7596, 'JOST',  'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '04-MAY-01', 4500, NULL, 50);
 (7603, 'CLARK', 'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '12-JUN-01', 4000, NULL, 50);
```

The Query that I have written is outputting the most hired employee only in one dept. Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong? I tried using Group By but am not able to do it the right way.

```
SELECT dpt.department_name, dpt.department_id, employee_name, hire_date, Salary 
    from dpt, emp
    where emp.department_id = dpt.department_id
    and
    hire_date = (select max(hire_date) from emp where department_id = emp.department_id)
    order by dpt.department_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by join

```
SELECT dpt.department_name, dpt.department_id, employee_name, hire_date, Salary 
    from dpt inner join emp on emp.department_id = dpt.department_id inner join
    (select emp.department_id, max(hire_date) as datemax from emp) x on  emp.department_id=x.department_id and emp.hire_date =x.datemax     
    order by dpt.department_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a table alias on the `where` clause in the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT dpt.department_name, dpt.department_id, employee_name, hire_date, Salary 
from dpt join
     emp
     on emp.department_id = dpt.department_id
where hire_date = (select max(hire_date) from emp emp2 where emp.department_id = emp2.department_id)
order by dpt.department_name;
```

Basically, the condition `where department_id = emp.department_id` fetches the column twice from the table in the subquery.  It is not correlated to the outer query.  By using proper table aliases, you get the correlation.

I also changed the `join` syntax to use the explicit form of joins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this query is behaving exactly like my query and is returning only one record

Comment: @nasiajaffri . . . Despite the explanation, I didn't put in `emp2.departmentid` in the condition.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT d.department_name,
       d.department_id,
       e.employee_name,
       e.hire_date,
       e.salary
  FROM dpt d,
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(hire_date) over(PARTITION BY department_id) max_hdate,
               emp.*
          FROM emp) e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
 WHERE e.hire_date = e.max_hdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this one:

```
with t as 
   (SELECT department_name, department_id, employee_name, hire_date, Salary,
      max(hire_date) over (partition by department_id) as max_hire_date
   from dpt join
      join emp using (department_id))
select *
from t
where max_hire_date = hire_date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT employee_id, employee_name, department_id FROM emp e1 WHERE hiredate = (SELECT max(hiredate) FROM emp e2 GROUP BY department_id HAVING e2.department_id=e1.department_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Data emp;
Input id name $ dept_no sal  title $ hire_date;
informat hire_date date9.;
Cards;
555  Kearny   200      7000   Manager 08Feb2102
666   williams   100       8000  Manager 30Jan2104
668  Mitchele 100        5000  clerk 14Jul2015 
777  Haberle     200      6000  Clerk 29Jan2001
888  Haberle    200       5000  Clerk 03Feb2015
 890     Johnson     300      4000  Analyst 02Mar2012
889  Dupont     400              5000  clerk  06May2011     .   
  990    McCabe     400       6000  Programmer 10Dec2015
999     Lopez           300           9000  Manager 12dec2105
;
Data Dept;
Input Dept_no  Dept_name $ Dept_city $ Dept_mgr;
cards;
100     Logistics  Wichita    666
200     Finance    Boise      555
300     Marketing  Pierre     666
400    HR              Paris     777
;
run;


proc sql;
select a.dept_no,c.dept_name,a.id,a.name,a.hire_date format=date9.
from emp a
inner join
(select dept_no,max(hire_date) as rec_date format=date9.
from emp group by 1) b
on a.dept_no=b.dept_no
inner join dept c
on a.dept_no=c.dept_no
where a.hire_date=b.rec_date
order by 5 desc;
quit;
                         dept_no  Dept_name        id  name      hire_date
                      ƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒ
                           300  Marketin        999  Lopez     12DEC2105
                           100  Logistic        666  williams  30JAN2104
                           200  Finance         555  Kearny    08FEB2102
                           400  HR              990  McCabe    10DEC2015
```

Comment: You should explain how this solution addresses the original problem: simply providing a wall of code isn't very illuminating.